# Bootstrap + CSS: How to set a div's height according to its width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to go from this
[image]

to this

[image]

In the first one, the `img` is responsive widthly. Its `width` is set to 100%, using bootstrap's `.img-responsive`.

However, to achieve the desired effect in second pic, we have to leave out part of the images'. To do this, one approach is to set the container of img to a fixed width and height, code goes like this:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="col-md-4 img-container">
    <img src="" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

(To use folloing approach, delete the `img-responsive' helper above.)

```
.img-container{
  height: 148px;
  width: 148px;
  img{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

However, using Bootstrap's grid to define every `<div>`'s width.,I don't want to set its witdh and height to a fixed value. That is, I want each `<img>` or its container to scale according to the `col-md-*`.

How can I do that, without using fixed width and height? Or put it simply, to set the height according to the width? (or just how to make a square)

Answer (score 4):

I have faced a similar need when building with Bootstrap's grid. I turned to JavaScript (requires jQuery) in order to remedy the situation. Here is my solution:
https://gist.github.com/SimpleAnecdote/d74412c7045d247359ed

It's called `squareThis()` because at first I used it only to make elements square, then I expanded it to mould any element into a rectangle with the help of a ratio. All you need to do is call the function after DOM is ready with any jQuery selector, #ID or .class:

```
squareThis('.classOfElementsToBeSquared');
```

The example above will default ot a ratio of 1:1 which will create a square. You may also call the function like this as well:

```
squareThis('.classOfElementsToBeMoulded', 0.67);
```

Which will create a 2:3 ratio rectangle (horizontal). You may also:

```
squareThis('.classOfElementsToBeMoulded', 1, '300');
```

Which will create squares out of your elements ONLY if the viewport is bigger than 300px.

In your case, I would use Bootstrap's `col-md-*` classes, add to all the grid elements a class like `.square-grid` and then:

```
squareThis('.square-grid');
```

I hope this function helps you. Please do let me know if you've got any questions about the function, ideas for improvement, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: This works great for my purposes!